# How to control when each statement in a for loop will execute

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, promise, setinterval

I am atm working with google maps api v3, doing both geocoding and geocoding-reverse.

The first thing I do is build an array of all my markers, and then I loop through the markers, in order to add the address to them (the geocoding in reverse). I do this via a promise. The maximum number of elements I expect my array to have at any given time is 20. 
I only get to see about 5 of my marker points getting proper addresses, as I get a OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code back.

Now I would like to implement a solution that will only try to query the geocoding service, at every fixed interval, like for instance every 2 seconds.
I have tried the following but it is not working, and I was hoping someone could give me some pointers on how to go about achieving what I just explained could be a possible solution.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(addPromiseDataToMarkerDetailsAndAddMarker(markers[i]), 2000);

}

function addPromiseDataToMarkerDetailsAndAddMarker(marker) {
  var returnedValue;
  asyncGeoCode(marker)
    .then(
      function(returnedValue) {
        id_address_map.set(returnedValue.CallID, returnedValue);
        addMarker(returnedValue);
        loadTimeline(returnedValue);
      },

      function(err) {
        addMarker(returnedValue);
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: note: once you fix your error, all *markers.length* markers will be added every 2 seconds, continuously. Is that what you expect?

Comment: nope, I was just writing a response to explain that. I expect each for loop entry to be made on the interval... here is jsfiddle to illustrate (the error behaviour) https://jsfiddle.net/HarrietFiddles/9rn3c5g0/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest change to your code is as follows:

```
var slowlyAddMarker(index) {
    addPromiseDataToMarkerDetailsAndAddMarker(markers[index]);
    index++;
    if (index < markers.length) {
        setTimeout(slowlyAddMarker, 2000, index);
    }
}
slowlyAddMarker(0);
```

The function will call itself every 2 seconds with the next index, until all markers have been done

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a 'closure' issue. Replace your for loop with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var intervalID = timer(i);
}
function timer(j)
{
  return window.setInterval(addPromiseDataToMarkerDetailsAndAddMarker(markers[j]), 2000);
}
```